# Summing columns in dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, calculated-columns

I am trying to add 3 columns' values to come up with a new column as total value. Code is below:

```
    df3[["Bronze","Gold","Silver"]] = 
    df3[["Bronze","Gold","Silver"]].astype("int")
    df3["Total Medal"]= df3.iloc[:, -3:0].sum(axis=1)
    df3[["Total Medal"]].astype("int")
```

I know that Bronze, Gold, Silver columns have 1 and 0 values and they are the last 3 columns in the dataframe. Their original types were "uint8" so I changed them to "int".

Total Medal column after these lines come out as type "float" (instead of int) and yield only the value 0. How can I properly add these columns?

Comment: For the last three columns you should slice it as `.iloc[:, -3:]`

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can e.g. be done using `assign`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create data frame
data = {"gold":np.random.choice([0,1],size=10),"silver":np.random.choice([0,1],size=10), "bronze":np.random.choice([0,1],size=10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#calculate new column and add to dataframe
df = df.assign(mysum=df.gold+df.silver+df.bronze)
```

Edit: `df["mysum"] = df.sum(axis=1)` only works if your dataframe only has the three relevant columns, because it sums over all columns (and not only over the three you want).

Comment: but `df["mysum"] = df.gold+df.silver+df.bronze` works and it a lot clearer than using `.assign`

Comment: Thanks, along with Dan's comment above, this solution worked too.

Comment: @Dan yes, your solution also works. `assign` is just one of several options (which is convenient if you want to do method chaining).

Answer (score 1):

To add the value of 3 columns to a new column simply do

```
    df['Total Medal'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This sums over all columns. The post asks to sum of three columns out of "at least three". So you solution does not work in this case in my opinion.